# The best method for check and uncheck checkbox in TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>aa</td><td>ss</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>aa</td><td>ss</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>aa</td><td>ss</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/6U5WH/

How is the best method for check and uncheck checkbox if i click on TR with current checkbox? Is possible with only HTML (label ?)? If not I would like use jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// when the row is clicked toggle the checked property
$('tr').click(function() {
     var $cb = $(this).find(':checkbox');
     $cb.prop('checked',!$cb.prop('checked'));
});
// prevent a click on the actual checkbox from bubbling to the row
$('tr :checkbox').click( function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6U5WH/1/

Answer (score 2):

Guys you are so fast here's my example also http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/6HtqB/3/

```
var selector = 'input[type=checkbox]';
$('tr').toggle(function() {
   $(this).find(selector).attr('checked', 'checked'); 
}, function() {
   $(this).find(selector).removeAttr('checked'); 
});
```

Comment: thanks, but in your example doesnt working checking only checkbox

Comment: yes, you have to use the stopPropagation(), you can get the code from @tvanfosson, small edit http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/6HtqB/4/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to us jQuery.

Try this code:

```
$('.offer').click(function(){ 
       var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
       $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox[0].checked);
 });
```